# Is there a way to install a matlab app without the .mlappinstall file?

Tags: matlab

An app I'd like to install has all of its component files downloadable on sourceforge, except for the .mlappinstall file. Is there anything I can do to install the app without this file? For context: I am working with the MacOS release of MATLABR2021B

Comment: What are "all of its components"? Does the app need to be installed? Are there no instructions in the project's documentation?

Comment: All of the components are what I'm assuming the package contents that would normally be put into the .mlappinstall file. The documentation is for windows, and unfortunately I don't have storage to use bootcamp. I assumed that I could install the package as an app into matlab and run it on MacOs.

Comment: You can probably package it yourself into an installation file and install it.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/app-creation.html

Comment: Do you specifically want it to work like an app with an icon in the toolbar? If you just want to be able to run it, you can add the folder(s) of source code to your path, that's all "installing" an app does (other than creating the icon)